# Connect Arduino digital pin to input pin and work as button

Tags: arduino, qpushbutton

In my project I need a push button to perform certain actions using Arduino. But unluckily I cannot buy a push button and I am in a bit of a hurry. Can I use the Arduino's 3.3v output pin and input pin to create a switch? I want to add two jumper wires and then connect them together. If both are connected then switch should be on. Can I do this? If yes then how?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware questions are off-topic.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the ouput AND input pins for that, use the VCC, GND and the input pins.

When you connect the digital input pin to VCC, it will register 1. When you connect to GND, it will register 0. If you leave the pin floating, you will get an undetermined result.

If you have a resistor handy (500R, 1K, 10K, does not matter much), you can do something like that:

```
Arduino GND <---->[resistor]<--+-------> Arduino input pin
                               |     
                               |      
                               +-= -]--> Arduino VCC
```

You connect the VCC wire to register true, and disconnect to register false. The resistor in series with GND will avoid the pin being left floating.

Comment: Is there any precautions? :D

Comment: No, it will work just fine. You will probably need to add some debouncing on your code, but for a quick test it will work.